# Can the characterset in TSynedit in Lazarus be set?

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I use TSynedit component in a program. I noticed when I use SynEdit1.Lines.SaveToFile(loadedfile);, then it is saved in utf8 encoding.
Is there a way to change that?. I changed font.charset property of Synedit1 object but it made no difference.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there are additional helper routines, but in general FPC/Lazarus haven't implemented the extra parameter to various .save* methods that Delphi/Unicode implemented